# No method error with form_for()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, web-applications

Having some issues setting up a form for my worker active record. I have a user has_many workers relationship and had nested routes for the workers. my form code is below in my new.html.erb file in the workers directory of the view.

```
 <h1>Setup a Worker</h1>
  <p>
   Enter in the information below to connect your worker to our service.
  </p>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@worker) do |w| %>

        <%= w.label :name %>
        <%= w.text_field :name %>

        <%=w.label :ip_address, "Ip address of the worker" %>
        <%=w.text_field :ip_address %>

        <%= w.submit "Create Worker", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my workers controller I have this

```
class WorkersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @worker = Worker.new
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

But when I try and load that Page I get this error

```
NoMethodError in Workers#new
```

and it points to this line

```
<%= form_for(@worker) do |w| %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for[@user, @worker] do |w| %>

    <%= w.label :name %>
    <%= w.text_field :name %>

    <%=w.label :ip_address, "Ip address of the worker" %>
    <%=w.text_field :ip_address %>

    <%= w.submit "Create Worker", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

  def new
    @worker = Worker.new
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  or some other way to load the user
  end
```

Comment: Why do I have to pass in the user for a form of a worker? is it because of the nested routing?

Comment: getting this error now for the form_for line after adding  user
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: try it with [] brakets, `<%= form_for[@user, @worker] do |w| %>`

Comment: Any1 have some good reading about how nested routes effects other parts ruby on rails I am current learning about ruby on rails. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks. Also I have the Worker model has a value called user_id to be used as a foreign key. would I enforce that at the controller and say worker = Worker.new
user = User.find(params[:user_id]
worker.user_id = user.id

Answer (score 0):

as rmagnum said, you need to nest your form also, so rails can build the relation you established, when im working with forms i like to use a gem called simple_form, here you can check this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form, it sure helps allot with relations.